# How to make a git branch the new master?

Tags: git, git-branch

A few days ago, I created a new git branch using:

```
git checkout -b release-1_5
```

Since creating that new branch, I've made additional changes & commits to it.

I'm the only developer, and no changes have been made to the actual 'master' in the meantime. I want to make the current state of the "release-1_5" branch the new master, and make 'master' the new working (HEAD?) branch, so that if I later do something like:

```
git checkout -b release-1_6
```

it will create a new branch that branches off from master

I know I could probably just keep doing "git checkout -b {new-branch-name}" (creating a linear branch-of-a-branch(-of-a-branch[-...]), but I'm pretty sure that would screw up Git's subway-like branch diagram.

If it matters, at the moment, the repo is entirely local, so there's no pulling/pushing or origin to worry about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing a simple merge of `release-1_5` back onto `master`. Since `master` has no new commits, it'll be a fast-forward merge.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge release-1_5
```

And that's it. You can optionally delete the `release-1_5` branch after that if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
git checkout release-1_5
git merge --strategy=ours master  # This will keep content of branch
git checkout master
git merge release-1_5             # this will fast-forward master to the merge
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not play with deleting branches.
What you want to do is to simply move latest commit from the `release-1_5` to `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge release-1_5
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~3 # Go back 3 commits. You *will* lose uncommitted work.
```